# select query to lookup column data against other column and extract value against other column in SQL

Tags: sql

| master_code | id | type | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | abcsjjjjsUV | doo | 852456 |
| abcsjjjjsUV | iydjfjdww | too | 951753 |
| abcsjjjjsUV | retslslfdf | too | null |

for a given table,
if `type = 'doo' then number` and `type = 'too' and number is not null then number`
number as it is.

but if `type = 'too' and number is null` then for that record map it's `master_code` in `id` column with record `type = 'doo'`, and corresponding `number` needs to populate instead of `null`.

expected output for, if `type = 'too' and number is null` then for that record map it's `master_code` in `id` column with record `type = 'doo'`, and corresponding `number` needs to populate instead of `null`.

| master_code | id | type | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | abcsjjjjsUV | doo | 852456 |
| abcsjjjjsUV | iydjfjdww | too | 951753 |
| abcsjjjjsUV | retslslfdf | too | 852456 |

Comment: Mysql and databricks are two different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your goal correct. Is this what you want? https://dbfiddle.uk/SVzD6NwI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a left-join with some conditions

```sql
SELECT
  t.master_code,
  t.id,
  t.type,
  IFNULL(t.number, t2.number) AS number
FROM YourTable t
LEFT JOIN YourTable t2
  ON t2.id = t.master_code
 AND t.type = 'too'
 AND t.number IS NULL
 AND t2.type = 'doo'
```